# Is there a neater way to solve this C# exercise?

Tags: c#

I am complete beginner in c#. So I am trying to solve this exercise:

> You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you. Write code to compute the result, encoded as an int value: 0=no ticket, 1=small ticket, 2=big ticket. If speed is 60 or less, the result is 0. If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1. If speed is 81 or more, the result is 2. Unless it is your birthday -- on that day, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases.

I solved it in the following way:

```
class SpeedLimit
{
    public int CaughtSpeeding(int speed, bool isBirthday)
    {
        if (speed < 61 || (speed < 66 && isBirthday == true))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        else if (speed >= 61 && speed <= 80 && isBirthday == false)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        else if (speed >= 66 && speed <= 85 && isBirthday == true)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return 2;
    }
}
```

It worked, but I had to manually add 5 each time in case of birthday. I think it was not the intention of this exercise. So is there any other convenient way to solve this?

Comment: You might like it more if you write a `SpeedIsInRange(startInclusive, endInclusive)` function.

Comment: Since you already have a working solution, this question is appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @krillgar My apology. I am new to this forum and still getting acquainted with the rules and regulations. So working solutions have no scope in this community?

Comment: @adnantanvir Correct. Stack Overflow is for "I have this code, and this is happening incorrectly. Why?" Code Review is for "I have this code, and it does everything I need it to, but I think it could be structured better. Help please!" As you saw, you'll get some help here on these questions, but you'll get more detailed assistance on Code Review.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest win is to deal with your birthday by knocking 5 off your speed:

```
public int CaughtSpeeding(int speed, bool isBirthday)
{
    if (isBirthday) speed -= 5;
    /*Birthday fully considered*/
```

Comment: While this algorithm behaves correctly,  `speed` will no longer represent the speed that the person is moving. I consider that to be structurally misleading. It could lead to problems if the variable is re-used.

Comment: @byxor: Fair point. You could create a new variable `effective_speed = isBirthday ? speed - 5 : speed;`.

Comment: the requirement says five higher in all cases, so I expected to see +=5, why -=5?

Comment: @derloopkat Because you're testing against the same speed as if you were going 5 lower. This removes the cushion of those 5 mph.

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-calculate speed to a variable that uses isBirthday to subtract 5. This makes the code a lot cleaner.

```
class SpeedLimit
{
    public int CaughtSpeeding(int speed, bool isBirthday)
    {
        var measuredSpeed = isBirthday
                                ? speed - 5
                                : speed;

        if (measuredSpeed < 61)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (measuredSpeed >= 61 &&
                 measuredSpeed <= 80)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `measuredX` usually implies the unprocessed X from the measurement, not the processed one that you have.

Answer (score 0):

A little math could also help. difference between `60` and `80` is `20`, consider offset as `40`, also since you said inclusive we consider to decrement speed by a factor in calculation. so ticket value would be calculated in this way.

```
ticket = Min(Max(speed - 1 - 40, 0) / 20, 2);
```

considering the birthday time

```
public static int CaughtSpeeding(int speed, bool isBirthday)
{
    if(isBirthday) speed -= 5;
    return (int)Math.Min(Math.Max(speed - 1 - 40, 0)/20, 2);
}
```